# Rewrite rule for wp

Tags: php, rewrite-rules

I have a URL which i want to change the query string to slug.

```
site.com/shop/?test=new
```

I want to get get the output as ?

```
site.com/new
```

But i don't want to get it redirect to any other page rather it should be on same page, where i can access the query string.

Comment: What's at `/shop`? Is it a page? Post archive?

Comment: its the shop page slug, the product archive

Comment: so to be clear, it's a page with a page ID with a page  template assigned, that acts as the shopfront? And not  the URL of a post archive, with an archive template, and no associated page? Does `/shop` appear in the pages section in the admin area? This is important

Comment: No its the default shop page for woocommerce